# hyperlinks problem with dvipdfm compiler

Tags: hyperref

I'm want to use hyperlinks in my PDF, but they don't work.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{extarticle}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\href{http://google.ru}{Google}

\end{document}
```

I'm using `dvipdfm` to compile my file.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 5):

Since the `dvipdfm` is used *after* the compilation with LaTeX, `hyperref` is not able to check the future. Therefore you have to specify the correct driver:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{extarticle}

\usepackage[dvipdfm]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\href{http://google.ru}{Google}

\end{document}
```

The default DVI driver for `hyperref` is not `dvipdfm` but usually `dvips`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case `hyperref` was already loaded by the class file and `\usepackage[dvipdfm]{hyperref}` lead to `! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package hyperref.`

With

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipdfm}{hyperref}
```

before `\documentclass` it worked.

Links work pdf, but not in dvi.

Comment: It should be sufficient to pass `dvipdfmx` as a class option.